# Viewing detail information by clicking on table row

Tags: jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have simple table in my jsp.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="employee" items="${employeeList}">
        <tr class=row>
            <td>${employee.id}</td>
            <td>${employee.name}</td>
            <td>${employee.surname}</td>
            <td>${employee.age}</td>
            <td>${employee.email}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

My controller :

```
   @Controller
public class BrowseController {

    @Autowired
    private SpringJdbcDao springJdbcDao;

    public void setSpringJdbcDao(SpringJdbcDao springJdbcDao) {
        this.springJdbcDao = springJdbcDao;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/browse")
    public String browseEmployees(Model model) {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>(springJdbcDao.getEmployeesList());
        model.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeList);
        return "browse";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/browse/details/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewDetails(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
        Employee employee = springJdbcDao.getEmployeeById(id);
        model.addAttribute("data", employee);
        return "details";
    }
}
```

I need to redirect to "/browse/details/{id}" to view detail information about employee by clicking on the row of the table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest adding a `data-` attribute to row to make it simpler to get employee ID :

```
<tr class=row data-emp_id="${employee.id}"></tr>
```

Now make AJAX call to server when row clicked:

```
var dataType='html';/* this is default and argument for `$.get` not needed for default, is shown for understanding*/
$('tr').click(function(){        
   $.get('/path/to server/', { id: $(this).data('emp_id') }, function( response){
       /* do something with response be it html, xml or JSON response*/
   }, dataType)
});
```

At server receive the `id` as you would any form control element with `name="id"` and send back corresponding data

Comment: `It doesn't help` doesn't explain much...what doesn't help?

Comment: click event doesn't trigger

Comment: is code wrapped in `docuemnt.ready` and have you included jQuery.js?

Comment: should work fine DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uqjuF/ ANy errros in browser console? And is server set to return data and path to server file is correct?

Comment: I need to pass the request in this way - /browse/details/5.  I am trying this way, but it doesn't work  -  $('tr').click(function () {
            $.get("/browse/details/" + $(this).data('id'))
        });

Comment: must send a key/value pair to server as I have shown by creating a data object. Just sending a value as you are doing, the server has no way to read it without the key. For example if server is running php would receive my example using `$_GET['id']` but without the key `$_GET` would be empty